# Integrating file management with Organic Groups

Tags: organic-groups, files

Using Drupal 7 and OG 2.x. I'm looking for a file manager to use so that each group has a files tab with the ability to create, move, delete files/folders for their group and read/write permission is only for the members of the specific group.

Is [filedepot](http://drupal.org/project/filedepot) the only module for this? I have found [elfinder](http://drupal.org/project/elfinder), [CKFinder](http://cksource.com/ckfinder/trial), and [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce), but it's unclear whether these are reasonably simply to integrate with OG.

Has anyone integrated a specific file manager with OG and is happy with how it's working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final answer is that elFinder was the file manager that ended up being the easiest to implement and it works nicely. Filedepot was promising, but by design, only a filedepot administrator can create a top level folder in Organic Groups mode. This means that if you have your site set up so users can create groups, it will fail creating the folder for the group unless you make all users fildepot admins. There may be a way to change this functionality in the code, but I didn't investigate it I also ran into trouble showing filedepot in a view and/or panel. So, I couldn't get a filedepot display to show up for each organic group.

If you use panels, elFinder shows up as "File Manager" under Miscellaneous when adding content to a panel. So, it was really easy to display an elFinder manager in each organic group. I did have to modify a few lines of code to grab the id of the current group, so that a correctly named directory was created the first time anyone opens elFinder in the group without a directory already being there.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer is that CKFinder doesn't integrate with OG out of the box, or easily at all. They do offer an access control list, but you would need to know the specific directories and specific people who need access. It won't work to create folders/permissions on the fly when creating groups or add/remove permissions as members are added/removed to the group. They mentioned that a custom plugin may be possible to do to modify the access control list but that it would be quite a bit of work. Java was recommended for the custom plugin.